# Parse - Class last date updated / modified?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, synchronization

I would like to check if my Parse Class was updated after a certain date (the date when I have sync my local database for the last time) so I can avoid to sync if my local data is already up to date.

Is there an easy way to do it?

is there a "last update" information anywhere? or something like the HTTP headers "last modified" ?

Thank you

Comment: Any luck with my code sample?

Comment: I have some issues comparing the dates but the logic is right so it should work!! :-D will update you

Comment: That's good news, post another update if you need any more help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there's a function built in to do this, however it's relatively easy code to make!

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "yourClass")
let cutOffDate = (some type of NSDate)
query.whereKey("updatedAt", greaterThan: cutOffDate)
query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock({ (first, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    //something was updated after date
                } else if error?.code == 101 {
                    //nothing was updated after date
                } else {
                    //something went wrong
                }
        })
```

Let me know if this works for you!